# How to combine hotspot in an image map?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, imagemap

I have created an image map with various hotspots and associated a link with each. One of the hotspots is discontiguous - Alaska and continental US on a world map. Is there a way to include two separate sets of coordinates in a single hotspot ?

I use the Jquery maphilight plugin by David Lynch to highlight the hotspots on mouseover. Is there a way within the maplight plugin to combine the two regions in a single hotspot and assign them to a link in a single href?

Is the maphilight plugin the best solution? Is there another plugin that would allow me to combine discontiguous poligons in the same area?

Here's my image map code:

```
    <map name="world"> 
    <area shape="poly" id="alaska" coords="2,20, 14,16, 15,12, 16,10, 21,7, 36,5, 29,15, 32,19, 28,21, 20,15, 11,19, 2,22" href="unitedstates.html" alt="usa" /> 
    <area shape="poly" id="usa" coords="30,27, 62,27, 75,27, 65,36, 58,43, 58,48, 57,44, 52,43, 47,43, 46,46, 43,50, 26,41, 25,34" href="unitedstates.html" alt="usa" /> 
    </map>
```

Answer (score 2):

I've  managed something similar but using the ImageMapster plugin - http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/

It's very well documented and the author went out of his way to help me out with some issues I was having.

To get grouping working you need to set `includeKeys`. Have a look at the USA map demo and look at Hawaii.

http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/examples/usa.html

Comment: Thanks for the plug! I literally just finished writing up how to use area groups, which might be useful to OP. There are some brand new features to manupulate groups in the current dev version: http://blog.outsharked.com/2012/03/area-groups-in-imagemapster.html -- also added "clickNavigate" option to, er, turn a map back into a regular imagemap and navigate on clicks. Ironically, Alaska was my example of that.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll have a look at that plugin.